# updating the text in the controller not working after converting the class from stateless to stateful

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

the code works fine when it's statelesswidget but after converting it to statefulwidget the textformfiled
stopped showing the text value from firestore.
when entering data the filed works just fine and the value stored in the firebase but when editing the the data the filed not showing the value to be edited and when entering the data in the filed new record is being stored in the firebase

```
class PostView extends StatefulWidget {
  PostView({Key key, this.edittingPost}) : super(key: key);
  final Post edittingPost;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CreatePostView();
  }
}

class CreatePostView extends State<PostView>{
  final airlineController = TextEditingController();
  final paxController = TextEditingController();
  final infantController = TextEditingController();
  final transitController = TextEditingController();
  final dateController = TextEditingController();


  Post edittingPost;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ViewModelBuilder<CreatePostViewModel>.reactive(
      viewModelBuilder: () => CreatePostViewModel(),
      onModelReady: (model) {
        // update the text in the controller
        airlineController.text = edittingPost?.airline ?? '';
        paxController.text = edittingPost?.pax ?? '';
        infantController.text = edittingPost?.infant ?? '';
        transitController.text = edittingPost?.transit ?? '';
        dateController.text = edittingPost?.date ?? '';

        model.setEdittingPost(edittingPost);
      },
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: !model.busy
                ? Icon(Icons.add)
                : CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.white),
                  ),
            onPressed: () {
              if (!model.busy) {
                model.addPost(date: dateController.text, airline: airlineController.text, pax: paxController.text,
                    infant: infantController.text, transit: transitController.text);
              }
            },
            backgroundColor:
                !model.busy ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : Colors.grey[600],
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  verticalSpace(40),
                  Text(
                    'Create Post',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26),
                  ),
                  verticalSpaceMedium,
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
                    height: 55.0,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.calendar_today,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Date of Flight',
                          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle),
                      controller: dateController,

                      onTap: () async{
                        DateTime date = DateTime(1900);
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

                        date = await showDatePicker(
                            context: context,
                            initialDate:DateTime.now(),
                            firstDate:DateTime(1900),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2100));

                        dateController.text = date.toIso8601String();},),
                  ),
                  verticalSpaceMedium,
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
                      height: 55.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.airplanemode_active,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Airline',
                          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
                        ),
                        controller: airlineController,
                      )),
                  verticalSpaceMedium,
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
                      height: 55.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.airline_seat_recline_extra,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Pax',
                          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
                        ),
                        controller: paxController,
                      )),
                  verticalSpaceMedium,
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
                      height: 55.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.child_friendly,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Infant',
                          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
                        ),
                        controller: infantController,
                      )),
                  verticalSpaceMedium,
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
                      height: 55.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.transit_enterexit,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          hintText: 'Transit',
                          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
                        ),
                        controller: transitController,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want see change text from textfromField - you have to use `setState()` where you will asssigned new value to variable.